# Getting information about a current status of an Brodcast value without receiving a message

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I managed it to receive information about a status beeing changed, but how can I just checkt the current status?

For Example:

When the bluetoothadapter changes the connectivity information, I can update the UI but when I start the app and want to show the current state (which didn't changed, so I didn't received an msg) it dosen't work... Some ideas?

```
BroadcastReceiver cBT_receive = new BroadcastReceiver() {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          int iBT_adapter_state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, mBluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
          int iBT_connection_state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_CONNECTION_STATE, mBluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
          ImageView Warning_image = findViewById(R.id.Status_Image);

          if(mBluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(intent.getAction()))
          {

              switch (iBT_adapter_state)
              {
                  case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                      Toast.makeText(context, "Bluetooth is turning on",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      Warning_image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.bt_foreground_yellow);
                      break;

                  case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                       Toast.makeText(context, "Bluetooth is on",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                      break;
              }
          }
          if (mBluetoothAdapter.ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(intent.getAction()))

              switch (iBT_connection_state)
              {
                  case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTED:
                      Toast.makeText(context, "Bluetooth is connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      Warning_image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.bt_foreground_green);
                      break;

                  case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                      Toast.makeText(context, "Bluetooth is disconnected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      Warning_image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.bt_foreground_red);
              }

      }
  };
```

The code above gives e Information when the status changed but not about the current status.

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

```
if(mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
{
    int icurrent_BT_state = mBluetoothAdapter.getState();

    switch (icurrent_BT_state)
    {
        case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
            Toast.makeText(context, "Bluetooth is already on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTED:
            Toast.makeText(context, "Bluetooth is already connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
}
```

Solution: **getState()**

Comment: please accept your answer. It will get this question off the list of open questions.